# UITextView in a UICollectionViewCell becomes unresponsive when returning from MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

for (MoviesCollectionViewCell *cell in myCollectionView.visibleCells) {
    [cell.videoTextView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}

[myCollectionView reloadData];

}
```

This is working but not sure if it's the most efficient way of doing it?

This solution also refreshes the font of the text meaning this would have to be placed inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath which I've been avoiding since it's already set in the AppDelegate.

Comment: Try with `[myCollectionView becomeFirstResponder]` once you return from `MPMoviePlayerViewController`

Comment: That doesn't work I'm afraid